# Kentico Azure blob integration

Tags: kentico, azure-blob-storage, kentico-12

On my Kentico project I have integrated Azure blob storage instead of saving files locally. Followed this article. https://docs.kentico.com/k12/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-azure-storage

Things are working alright except for a one problem. Now all the files are accessible publically. There are some PDF files in the media library that I won't only the logged in users to view but now any one can view these files. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Files in Media Library are always accessible via the direct link and you can't restrict them to logged-in users only. Regardless it's Azure storage or local disk.

But there are two ways of achieving this:

1. Presentation-only restrictions. When you present those PDF links to the website user - display them only to logged-in users. The files will still be accessible via direct links but only logged-in users will see them.
2. Hard restrictions. As far as I know, these restrictions can be set up only for [files stored in CMS tree](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/managing-website-content/working-with-files/content-tree-files). This approach will check permissions when accessing files via direct link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing files in blob there is no way. You can restrict the access to the whole container with SAS token (or individual blob), but not a to a specific folder. Folder is purely virtual structure, it exists only in a file path.